# Flex Incompatible Override, bug?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm writing an extension to the Flex DataGridColumn class. I want to override the editable and sortable properties so that I can dispatch an event in the setter. So I looked up the method signature from the Adobe Docs (I'm using Flex 3.5 compiler):

Language Version:   ActionScript 3.0

Implementation

```
public function get editable():Boolean
public function set editable(value:Boolean):void
public var sortable:Boolean
```

I should be able to override both the setter for editable, and use a setter to override the functionality of sortable.

in my code I have:

```
public override function set editable(value:Boolean):void {
    super.editable = value;
    //code to dispatch event
}
```

and

```
public override function set sortable(value:Boolean):void{
   super.sortable = value;
   //code for event
}
```

However I get a #1023 error : Incompatible override. I've tried all sorts of combinations on the method signatures, but these are exactly the same as the ones in the docs above.

What gives? Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: Apparently the documentation is not in line with the actual source code. Both editable and sortable are variables in DataGridColumn.as. Anyway I can override them with a setter/getter without modifying the base class?
DataGridColumn.as Source:

```
public var editable:Boolean = true;
public var sortable:Booelan = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override variable as property(get/set). BTW, `editable` and `sortable` became properties in SDK 4.0.